# Dotnetnuke Skin Issue

Tags: dotnetnuke, skin

Hi Chris We using DotNetNuke 6.2.3 enterprise edition. In localhost all images i referred in skin file was came both login and Logout Period.I followed the following steps.1st I need to create one child portal. so i went **Host-->SiteManagement-->Add New Site-->** i choosed the child portal and also site title,description,keywords.I can able to create child site. After that i went **Admin-->SiteWizard-->Blank Template-->Replace Content-->I choosed my installed skin and container in portal**.And also I added HTML Modules. Both Skin and HTML Contains image tag.

Now I login as a superuser -->My content, Images  ,Style properties everything came fine.
Once i logout skin file not loaded due to that page alignment collapsed. Next in chrome i went  inspect element i am not able to open those images.If i login as a host i am able to see those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please share one of the URLs to the images that aren't working?

Perhaps you have the permissions in your DNN file manager setup so that you have to be logged in to view all of the files in the folder. You can go to the file manager, click on a folder, and manager permissions from there.